# Duplicating an array's elements using functional programming

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, functional-programming

I'm trying to duplicate each element in an array, but using functional style.

I have this currently:

```
["a", "b", "c"]
```

And I'm getting this:

```
["a","a","b","b","c","c"]
```

So far I have tried the following, mapping each element to an array, then using flat() to get a 1d array. Is there a cleaner way because it feels like I'm abusing map and flat.

```
["a", "b", "c"].map(item => [item, item]).flat();
```

Is there a better way to do this?

---

I was trying to provide a example as simple as possible but left some details out. The real input is not sorted because elements are not comparable.
It's something like:

```
[
  {
    a:"a"
    b:"b"
  },
  {
    c: 1
    d: 2
  },
  {
    apple: {},
    sellers: ["me", "her"]
  }
]
```

The duplicated result should be something like this, where duplicated elements are next to each other:

```
[
  {
    a:"a"
    b:"b"
  },
  {
    a:"a"
    b:"b"
  },
  {
    c: 1
    d: 2
  },
  {
    c: 1
    d: 2
  },
  {
    apple: {},
    sellers: ["me", "her"]
  },
  {
    apple: {},
    sellers: ["me", "her"]
  }
]
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you edited your question to include: 1. Is the input array always sorted as in your example? 2. Should the order of the output match the order of the input?  Several of the answers assume sorted input.

Comment: If you don't consider complexity and performance , than , basically you can use destructuring [...arr,...arr].sort(). And by the way functional programming does not refer to Arrow-Functions (as you used in your example) but rather the behavior and meaning of the function which should act like Mathematical functions by receiving parameters  and returning result. So in your case you would like to write something like this (to align with functional programming):
const duplicateArrayItems = (arr) => [...arr,...arr].sort();
let  array = ['a','b','c'], result = duplicateArrayItems(array);

Comment: @MattMorgan thanks for pointing that out, I was trying to provide an example as simple as possible but that caused important details to be left out. 1) input is not sorted because the real actual input is an array of complex objects that are not sortable. 2) the order of the output should be like a,a,b,b,c,c duplicated elements are next to each other

Comment: @Reek thanks for the clarification.  I've edited my answer to reflect your new input data.

Answer (score 6):

`Array.reduce` is semantically the appropriate method here: take an object (in this case an array) and return an object of a different type, or with a different length or shape (note: edited to use Array.push for faster performance per @slider suggestion):

**EDIT: I've edited my answer to reflect OP's updated input data.**  Note also, that this solution is cross-browser and NodeJS compatible without requiring transpilation.

```js
let data = [
  {
    a:"a",
    b:"b",
  },
  {
    c: 1,
    d: 2
  },
  {
    apple: {},
    sellers: ["me", "her"]
  }
];

let result = data
  .reduce((acc, el) => {
    acc.push(el, el);
    return acc;
  }, []);
  
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

Otherwise you could `map` each element, duplicating it, then combine them:

```js
let data = [
  {
    a:"a",
    b:"b",
  },
  {
    c: 1,
    d: 2
  },
  {
    apple: {},
    sellers: ["me", "her"]
  }
];

let result = data.map(item => [item, item]).reduce((acc, arr) => acc.concat(arr));

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

As mentioned in other answers here, either of these approaches have the advantage of not requiring the original array to have been sorted.

Comment: concat also takes multiple arguments ... `=> acc.concat(el, el)`

Comment: Reduce is overkill. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Comment: @kemicofa using `concat().sort()` as a few have suggested only works when the original array was sorted.  If you have a better suggestion please post an answer.

Comment: `acc.concat(el).concat(el)` may be less code but it's much worse time complexity. I would use `push(el, el)` with a `return acc` statement because `push` is *O(1)* as opposed to `concat` which is *O(n)* since it's building a new array.

Comment: @slider thanks for the suggestion!  That sounds like a great optimization.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the function `reduce` and concatenate the same object on each iteration.

```js
let array = ["a", "b", "c"],
    result = array.reduce((a, c) => a.concat(c, c), []);
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Is `Array.prototype.concat.call...` really necessary?  Couldn't this just be done by `array.concat(array).sort()`?

Comment: Makes sense.  There's still more than one way to do it.  For instance by making a copy of the original array with `slice`

Comment: How's `array.concat(array)` going to mutate the original? The docs say *"This method does not change the existing arrays, but instead returns a new array."*

Comment: Also this assumes the original array is sorted. What if the original is `['b', 'a', 'c']`?

Comment: Well, with `['b', 'a', 'c']` this will result in `["a","a","b","b","c","c"]` but the desired output may be `['b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'c']` (I'm not sure though).

Comment: if you're just going to use `reduce`, why not `arr.reduce((acc,x) => acc.concat([x,x]), [])`?

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend [Array.prototype.flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) -

```js
const twice = x =>
  [ x, x ]
  
console .log
  ( [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ] .flatMap (twice) // [ 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c' ]
  , [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ] .flatMap (twice) // [ 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5 ]
  )
```

`flatMap` is useful for all kinds of things -

```js
const tree =
  [ 0, [ 1 ], [ 2, [ 3 ], [ 4, [ 5 ] ] ] ]
  
const all = ([ value, ...children ]) =>
  [ value ] .concat (children .flatMap (all))
  
console .log (all (tree))
// [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

really cool things -

```js
const ranks =
  [ 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A' ]
  
const suits =
  [ '♡', '♢', '♤', '♧' ]

console .log
  ( ranks .flatMap (r =>
      suits .flatMap (s =>
        [ [ r, s ] ]
      )
    )
  )

// [ ['J','♡'], ['J','♢'], ['J','♤'], ['J','♧']
// , ['Q','♡'], ['Q','♢'], ['Q','♤'], ['Q','♧']
// , ['K','♡'], ['K','♢'], ['K','♤'], ['K','♧']
// , ['A','♡'], ['A','♢'], ['A','♤'], ['A','♧']
// ]
```

`flatMap` is just a specialised `Array.prototype.reduce` and is easy to implement in environments where `Array.prototype.flatMap` is not already supported -

```js
const identity = x =>
  x

const flatMap = (xs = [], f = identity) =>
  xs .reduce ((r, x) => r . concat (f (x)), [])

const ranks =
  [ 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A' ]

const suits =
  [ '♡', '♢', '♤', '♧' ]

console.log
  ( flatMap (ranks, r =>
      flatMap (suits, s =>
        [ [ r, s ] ]
      )
    )
  )

// [ ['J','♡'], ['J','♢'], ['J','♤'], ['J','♧']
// , ['Q','♡'], ['Q','♢'], ['Q','♤'], ['Q','♧']
// , ['K','♡'], ['K','♢'], ['K','♤'], ['K','♧']
// , ['A','♡'], ['A','♢'], ['A','♤'], ['A','♧']
// ]
```

Comment: That is really nice, although of limited practical use until  there’s Microsoft and Node support.

Comment: @MarkMeyer `flatMap` is just a specialised `reduce` - I've updated the answer to show how to use `flatMap` in an environment that doesn't support `Array.prototype.flatMap`

Answer (score 2):

You could just do this:

```
var arr = ["a", "b", "c"];
arr = arr.concat(arr).sort();
```

This is one of the simplest methods to do what you are asking to do.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use flatMap():

```
const source = ["a", "b", "c"];
const result = source.flatMap(item => [item, item]);
```

> [ 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c' ]

A little bit of classic:

```
let source = ["a", "b", "c"];

const originalLength = source.length;
for(let i = 0; i <= originalLength + (originalLength - 2); i++) {
  source.splice(i, 0, source[i++]);
}
```

> [ 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c' ]